# Potential phishing or malicious code on this page?

Tags: security

Recently received a link to a webpage that was supposed to be a file to review. I became suspicious and used web-sniffer.net to pull the code. It looks to me like it's trying to maliciously get access to Facebook.

Does anyone have thoughts on this? Thanks for your help

## Code Below -

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="en-gb"><head>
  <title>View Docs Online - The easiest way to view documents online</title>
    <meta name="description" content="View Docs Online allows you to view the most common document types in a simple and fast way. No need to install any software!">
    <meta name="keywords" content="view documents online, documents, viewer, remondini, doc, office, pdf, docx, xlsx, pptx, online, docs, view, document, firefox, open">
    <meta name="author" content="Denis Remondini">
  <meta name="robots" content="noarchive">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta property="og:title" content="View Docs Online - The easiest way to view documents online">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.viewdocsonline.com">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.viewdocsonline.com/images/thumbnail_facebook.png">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="View Docs Online">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="117978301565673">

  <link rel="icon" href="http://www.viewdocsonline.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.viewdocsonline.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="View_files/jquery.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="View_files/thickbox-3.css" type="text/css" media="screen">    
        <!-- Additional IE/Win specific style sheet (Conditional Comments) -->
        <!--[if lte IE 7]>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.tabs-ie-2.7.4.css" type="text/css" media="projection, screen">
          <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="View_files/main-1.css" type="text/css">  
           <script src="View_files/ga.js" async="" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="View_files/main-1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tabsSection').tabs({ 
          fxSpeed: 'normal'
        });
                $('#tabsSection').css("display","block");
            });
    </script>

     <style> 
    <!--
.button{
 text-decoration:none; 
 text-align:center; 
 padding:11px 32px; 
 border:solid 1px #3866c9; 
 -webkit-border-radius:5px 4px 4px 4px;             border-radius: 5px 4px 4px 4px;           -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;           -moz-border-radius-topright:4px;           -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px;           -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px;  
 font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 color:#E5FFFF; 
 background:#ffffff; 
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 11px #0d28fa, inset 8px 9px 6px #f5f5f5; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #0d28fa,  inset 8px 9px 6px #f5f5f5;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 11px #0d28fa, inset 8px 9px 6px #f5f5f5;  

  }
    -->
   </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-55641-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.viewdocsonline.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script><style type="text/css">.fb_hidden{position:absolute;top:-10000px;z-index:10001}
.fb_invisible{display:none}
.fb_reset{background:none;border:0;border-spacing:0;color:#000;cursor:auto;direction:ltr;font-family:"lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:1;margin:0;overflow:visible;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;text-indent:0;text-shadow:none;text-transform:none;visibility:visible;white-space:normal;word-spacing:normal}
.fb_reset > div{overflow:hidden}
.fb_link img{border:none}
.fb_dialog{background:rgba(82, 82, 82, .7);position:absolute;top:-10000px;z-index:10001}
.fb_dialog_advanced{padding:10px;-moz-border-radius:8px;-webkit-border-radius:8px;border-radius:8px}
.fb_dialog_content{background:#fff;color:#333}
.fb_dialog_close_icon{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;_background-image:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yL/r/s816eWC-2sl.gif);cursor:pointer;display:block;height:15px;position:absolute;right:18px;top:17px;width:15px;top:8px\9;right:7px\9}
.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_icon{top:5px;left:5px;right:auto}
.fb_dialog_padding{background-color:transparent;position:absolute;width:1px;z-index:-1}
.fb_dialog_close_icon:hover{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -15px transparent;_background-image:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yL/r/s816eWC-2sl.gif)}
.fb_dialog_close_icon:active{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -30px transparent;_background-image:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yL/r/s816eWC-2sl.gif)}
.fb_dialog_loader{background-color:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #606060;font-size:24px;padding:20px}
.fb_dialog_top_left,
.fb_dialog_top_right,
.fb_dialog_bottom_left,
.fb_dialog_bottom_right{height:10px;width:10px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute}
.fb_dialog_top_left{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 0;left:-10px;top:-10px}
.fb_dialog_top_right{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 -10px;right:-10px;top:-10px}
.fb_dialog_bottom_left{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 -20px;bottom:-10px;left:-10px}
.fb_dialog_bottom_right{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 -30px;right:-10px;bottom:-10px}
.fb_dialog_vert_left,
.fb_dialog_vert_right,
.fb_dialog_horiz_top,
.fb_dialog_horiz_bottom{position:absolute;background:#525252;filter:alpha(opacity=70);opacity:.7}
.fb_dialog_vert_left,
.fb_dialog_vert_right{width:10px;height:100%}
.fb_dialog_vert_left{margin-left:-10px}
.fb_dialog_vert_right{right:0;margin-right:-10px}
.fb_dialog_horiz_top,
.fb_dialog_horiz_bottom{width:100%;height:10px}
.fb_dialog_horiz_top{margin-top:-10px}
.fb_dialog_horiz_bottom{bottom:0;margin-bottom:-10px}
.fb_dialog_iframe{line-height:0}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_title{background:#6d84b4;border:1px solid #3b5998;color:#fff;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin:0}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_title > span{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yd/r/Cou7n-nqK52.gif)
no-repeat 5px 50%;float:left;padding:5px 0 7px 26px}
body.fb_hidden{-webkit-transform:none;height:100%;margin:0;overflow:visible;position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:0;width:100%}
.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ya/r/3rhSv5V8j3o.gif)
white no-repeat 50% 50%;min-height:100%;min-width:100%;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;z-index:10001}
.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading.centered{max-height:590px;min-height:590px;max-width:500px;min-width:500px}
#fb-root #fb_dialog_ipad_overlay{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;min-height:100%;z-index:10000}
#fb-root #fb_dialog_ipad_overlay.hidden{display:none}
.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading iframe{visibility:hidden}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header{-webkit-box-shadow:white 0 1px 1px -1px inset;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#738ABA), to(#2C4987));border-bottom:1px solid;border-color:#1d4088;color:#fff;font:14px Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;text-overflow:ellipsis;text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0;vertical-align:middle;white-space:nowrap}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header table{-webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased;height:43px;width:100%
}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header td.header_left{font-size:12px;padding-left:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:60px
}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header td.header_right{font-size:12px;padding-right:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:60px
}
.fb_dialog_content .touchable_button{background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#4966A6),
color-stop(0.5, #355492), to(#2A4887));border:1px solid #29447e;-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, .117188) 0 1px 1px inset,
rgba(255, 255, 255, .167969) 0 1px 0;display:inline-block;margin-top:3px;max-width:85px;line-height:18px;padding:4px 12px;position:relative}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header .touchable_button input{border:none;background:none;color:#fff;font:12px Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;margin:2px -12px;padding:2px 6px 3px 6px;text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header .header_center{color:#fff;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;line-height:18px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_content{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y9/r/jKEcVPZFk-2.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;border:1px solid #555;border-bottom:0;border-top:0;height:150px}
.fb_dialog_content .dialog_footer{background:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #555;border-top-color:#ccc;height:40px}
#fb_dialog_loader_close{float:left}
.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_button{text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0}
.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_icon{visibility:hidden}
.fb_iframe_widget{display:inline-block;position:relative}
.fb_iframe_widget span{display:inline-block;position:relative;text-align:justify}
.fb_iframe_widget iframe{position:absolute}
.fb_iframe_widget_lift{z-index:1}
.fb_hide_iframes iframe{position:relative;left:-10000px}
.fb_iframe_widget_loader{position:relative;display:inline-block}
.fb_iframe_widget_fluid{display:inline}
.fb_iframe_widget_fluid span{width:100%}
.fb_iframe_widget_loader iframe{min-height:32px;z-index:2;zoom:1}
.fb_iframe_widget_loader .FB_Loader{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y9/r/jKEcVPZFk-2.gif) no-repeat;height:32px;width:32px;margin-left:-16px;position:absolute;left:50%;z-index:4}
.fb_connect_bar_container div,
.fb_connect_bar_container span,
.fb_connect_bar_container a,
.fb_connect_bar_container img,
.fb_connect_bar_container strong{background:none;border-spacing:0;border:0;direction:ltr;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:1;margin:0;overflow:visible;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;text-indent:0;text-shadow:none;text-transform:none;visibility:visible;white-space:normal;word-spacing:normal;vertical-align:baseline}
.fb_connect_bar_container{position:fixed;left:0 !important;right:0 !important;height:42px !important;padding:0 25px !important;margin:0 !important;vertical-align:middle !important;border-bottom:1px solid #333 !important;background:#3b5998 !important;z-index:99999999 !important;overflow:hidden !important}
.fb_connect_bar_container_ie6{position:absolute;top:expression(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? document.documentElement.scrollTop+"px":body.scrollTop+"px")}
.fb_connect_bar{position:relative;margin:auto;height:100%;width:100%;padding:6px 0 0 0 !important;background:none;color:#fff !important;font-family:"lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif !important;font-size:13px !important;font-style:normal !important;font-variant:normal !important;font-weight:normal !important;letter-spacing:normal !important;line-height:1 !important;text-decoration:none !important;text-indent:0 !important;text-shadow:none !important;text-transform:none !important;white-space:normal !important;word-spacing:normal !important}
.fb_connect_bar a:hover{color:#fff}
.fb_connect_bar .fb_profile img{height:30px;width:30px;vertical-align:middle;margin:0 6px 5px 0}
.fb_connect_bar div a,
.fb_connect_bar span,
.fb_connect_bar span a{color:#bac6da;font-size:11px;text-decoration:none}
.fb_connect_bar .fb_buttons{float:right;margin-top:7px}
.fbpluginrecommendationsbarleft,
.fbpluginrecommendationsbarright{position:fixed !important;bottom:0;z-index:999}
.fbpluginrecommendationsbarleft{left:10px}
.fbpluginrecommendationsbarright{right:10px}
     .auto-style1 {
       margin-top: 155px;
     }
     .auto-style2 {
       border-width: 0px;
     }
     </style></head>
<body><div style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px;" id="WzTtDiV"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="View_files/tooltip-5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="View_files/all.js"></script>
<div>

    <div class=" fb_reset" id="fb-root"><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div><iframe src="View_files/LEdxGgtB9cN.htm" style="border: medium none;" tab-index="-1" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" aria-hidden="true" id="fb_xdm_frame_http" allowtransparency="true" name="fb_xdm_frame_http" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><iframe src="View_files/LEdxGgtB9cN_002.htm" style="border: medium none;" tab-index="-1" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" aria-hidden="true" id="fb_xdm_frame_https" allowtransparency="true" name="fb_xdm_frame_https" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div></div><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div></div></div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function getLoggedInText(fbResponse) {
    var text = 'Logged in as ' + fbResponse.name + '. <a href="#" onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Facebook\', \'Facebook Logout\']); FB.logout(function() { /*var userInfo = document.getElementById(\'fbPanel\'); userInfo.innerHTML = getLoggedOutText(); */}); return false;" ><img style="vertical-align: text-bottom" border="0" id="fb_logout_image" src="/images/social/fblogout.gif" alt="Logout"/></a>';
    //alert(text);
    return text; 
  }

  function getLoggedOutText() {
    var text = 'You are not logged in yet. <a style="color: #5990A9" onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'ViewPopup\', \'Why login\']);" href="whylogin.php?height=400&amp;width=550" class="thickbox" target="_blank" title="Login">Why should you do it?</a> ';
    text = text + '<a href="#" onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Facebook\', \'Facebook Login\']); FB.login(function() { /*var userInfo = document.getElementById(\'fbPanel\'); userInfo.innerHTML = getLoggedInText(); */}, {scope: \'publish_actions\'}); return false;" ><img style="vertical-align: text-bottom" border="0" id="fb_login_image" src="/images/social/fblogin.jpg" alt="Login"/></a>';
    //alert(text);
    return text;
  }

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({ appId: '117978301565673', 
      status: true, 
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true});

  function updateButton(response) {
  var userInfo = document.getElementById('fbPanel');
    if (response.authResponse) {
      //user is already logged in and connected     
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        userInfo.innerHTML = getLoggedInText(response); 
    });    
    } else {
      //user is not connected to your app or logged out
      userInfo.innerHTML = getLoggedOutText(); 
    }
  }

  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);  
};
      /*FB.init({
    appId   : '117978301565673',
    oauth: true,
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
    });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
     // alert('ciao');
        $.get('ajax/fbLoginPanel1.php', function(data) {
        $('#fbPanel').html(data);
        alert(data);
        FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fbPanel'));     
        });
      //login-btn
      //window.location.reload();
    });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Facebook', 'Login with facebook account']);
    });*/
    </script>

</div>
  <div id="main" style="left: 50%; top: 45%; height: 724px; width: 803px;">
          <div class="logo">
              <img alt="View Docs Online" src="View_files/logo.jpg" border="0">
            </div>
            <div class="slogan">
               <font color="black">The easiest way to view documents online
            </div>    
            <div style="font-size: small; padding: 5px; color: rgb(89, 144, 169); width: 716px; margin: 10pt auto; text-align: center;">
        <font color="red">New!</font> Login with your <span lang="en-us">
              Email</span> and <span lang="en-us">view</span> all your docs!<br /> <br />  

<strong>Choose your email provider below and login:</strong><br />
              <br />
              <a href="YLogin.htm">
              <img alt="" height="48" src="View_files/yahoo.jpg" width="132" class="auto-style2" /></a><span lang="en-us">&nbsp;
              </span>
              <a href="ALogin.htm">
              <img alt="" class="auto-style2" height="48" src="View_files/aol.jpg" width="132" /></a>&nbsp;
              <a href="GLogin.htm">
              <img alt="" class="auto-style2" height="48" src="View_files/gmail.jpg" width="132" /></a>&nbsp;
              <a href="HLogin.htm">
              <img alt="" height="48" src="View_files/hotmail.jpg" width="132" class="auto-style2" /></a>&nbsp;
              <a href="OLogin.htm">
              <img alt="" height="48" src="View_files/other.jpg" width="132" class="auto-style2" /></a></div>  

    <div>
      <div id="fbPanel" style="font-size: small; padding: 5px; color: #91B6DB; text-align: center" class="auto-style1">
        You are not logged in yet. <a style="color: #5990A9" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ViewPopup', 'Why login']);" href="http://www.viewdocsonline.com/whylogin.php?height=400&amp;width=550" class="thickbox" target="_blank" title="Login">Why should you do it?</a></div>
            <div class="links">     
         <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ViewPopup', 'My docs']);" href="http://www.viewdocsonline.com/mydocs.php?height=350&amp;width=550" class="thickbox" target="_blank" title="My docs">My docs</a>
         <span class="separator">|</span> 
         <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ViewPopup', 'Support']);" href="http://www.viewdocsonline.com/support.php?height=400&amp;width=550" class="thickbox" target="_blank" title="Support">Support</a>
         <span class="separator">|</span>
         <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound Links', 'Blog']);" href="http://www.viewdocsonline.com/blog" target="_blank">Blog</a>
         <span class="separator">|</span>
         <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ViewPopup', 'About']);" href="http://www.viewdocsonline.com/about.php?height=350&amp;width=550" class="thickbox" target="_blank" title="About us">About us</a>
         <span class="separator">|</span> 
           <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ViewPopup', 'Terms']);" href="http://www.viewdocsonline.com/terms.php?height=400&amp;width=550" class="thickbox" target="_blank" title="Terms and Conditions">Terms and Conditions</a>      

            </div>    
    </div>
            <div class="footer">
                Copyright © 2009-2014 Denis Remondini. All Rights Reserved. 
            </div>
</div>
<div id="listOfFilesSupported" style="display: none;">
<p>
<b>Readable files</b>
</p>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1em">
            Microsoft Office:
      <div style="display: inline-block; height: 16px; width: 16px; background: url(&quot;/images/sprites/filetypes.png&quot;); background-position: 0px -130px; vertical-align: bottom;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="display: inline;">doc, docx</div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; height: 16px; width: 16px; background: url(&quot;/images/sprites/filetypes.png&quot;); background-position: 0px -78px; vertical-align: bottom;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="display: inline;">ppt, pptx, pps</div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; height: 16px; width: 16px; background: url(&quot;/images/sprites/filetypes.png&quot;); background-position: 0px 0px; vertical-align: bottom;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="display: inline;">xls, xlsx</div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1em">PDF: 
         <div style="display: inline-block; height: 16px; width: 16px; background: url(&quot;/images/sprites/filetypes.png&quot;); background-position: 0px -52px; vertical-align: bottom;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="display: inline;">pdf, ps</div>
    </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1em">Open Office: 
        <div style="display: inline-block; height: 16px; width: 16px; background: url(&quot;/images/sprites/filetypes.png&quot;); background-position: 0px -26px; vertical-align: bottom;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="display: inline;">odt, odp, ods, odg, odf, sxw, sxc, sxi, sxd</div>
    </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1em">eBooks: 
        <div style="display: inline-block; height: 16px; width: 16px; background: url(&quot;http://www.siliconvalleyblog.de/ebook.gif&quot;); background-position: 0px -160px; vertical-align: bottom;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="display: inline;">epub</div>
    </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1em">Text: 
        <div style="display: inline-block; height: 16px; width: 16px; background: url(&quot;/images/sprites/filetypes.png&quot;); background-position: 0px -104px; vertical-align: bottom;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="display: inline;">txt, rtf</div>
    </div>
</div>



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, most definitely phishing. I got a very similar thing in my email that was sent from an email account of a friend who had no idea about it. 
It asked me to log in and stole my password.

Comment: Alex, it stole your password for Facebook?